# Unable to upload a file to foldergrid using API

Tags: api, http

Trying to use folder grid api to upload a file. There are 2 steps.

1. Calling provision a file to get a location with a guid.
2. Uploading the actual file using a PUT.

I am able to do the first call and get a location of the type `https://files.foldergrid.com/upload/xxx`. I then try to upload the file using this as my location and keep getting

```
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host files.foldergrid.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

from the server not sure what I am missing?
Here is the code I am using:

After calling the provision api I get back a url which I store in
$url = 'https://files.foldergrid.com/upload/xxx'
and I have the path to the file I want to upload in file 
$file = 'some path to file'
then I have call the following method:

```
    public function putFile($file,$url) {

    $headers = array(

    'fg-eap: false',
    'fg-md5:'.md5_file($file),

        );

    $fh = fopen($file, "rb");

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_PUT,true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);


    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($file));

    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true );                   

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    fclose($fg);

    curl_close($curl);
    return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've posted looks to have everything needed except the Content-Type header. Try setting your headers array as:

```
$headers = array(
  'fg-eap: false',
  'fg-md5:'.md5_file($file),
  'Content-Type: binary/octet-stream'
);
```

Also, in response to your query here we've posted an updated PHP client sample under [our API documentation here](http://foldergrid.com/api/index.html#sample-code-examples).

Comment: That was one of my errors. I had another error in my location variable it had spaces at the end that is why I kept seeing a malformed url where I should have seen a PUT request.